# CSS transform does not work on android when "user-scalable=no" is set in viewport

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I have a big problem:

The CSS transform translation does not work when I set the "user-scalable=no" in page viewport but it works fine in any computer browser:

```
#progress-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #21232A;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;

    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(55%) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(55%) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(55%) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(55%) rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(55%) rotate(45deg);

    pointer-events: none;
}
```

My viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
```

I really need the "user-scalable=no" in my page because I have a header and footer which use it to fixing them on the page(bypassing a android bug)

ANDROID TESTED VERSION: 2.3.x

Any workaround is welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to use `position:fixed` on the header and footer?